# What is 1 - P(X) where P(X) is the probability of X happening N times.

Tags: probability

Let's say that P(X) is probability of X happening N times, like from the example I'm studying it would be probability of surviving all N accidents.

Then what's 1-P(X) : The text claims it to be probability of not surviving at least one of the accidents. I'm unsure how this result comes out to be. For instance, why this is not probability of not surviving all the accidents or dying in all the accidents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is the event that the 1st accident is survived AND the 2nd accident is survived AND ... AND the $N$th accident is survived. What is the complement of that event? It's the event that at least one accident is not survived. Let's see why.

If at least one accident is not survived, then certainly the event $X$ has not happened. So the event that at least one accident is not survived is contained in $X^C$. Conversely, choose an outcome in $X^C$. Since it's in $X^C$, it can't be the case that every accident was survived, i.e., there exists at least one accident that was not survived.

This holds in general: for an event of the form $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n$, its complement is $A_1^C \cup A_2^C \cup \cdots \cup A_n^C$ (applying DeMorgan's Law). That is, the complement of *all* of the $A_i$ occuring is *at least one* of the $A_i$ not occuring.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds something like the event $X$ is the event that there are $N$ survivors in $N$ accidents.

The complement is  surviving $M \neq N$ accidents. If we assume that there are only $N$ trials, then this is equivalent to saying there is at least one death in $N$ trials.

Hence
$$P(X) = 1-P(X) = 1-P(\text{At least one death})$$